# Spring boot 2 loading static resource html

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

There are different solutions for serving a static HTML from spring boot. But here is a simple html am trying to package as a WAR and test it using embedded tomcat. But am unable to serve the static html. I get a 404 error.

Here is the log am seeing:

```
2018-11-28 07:30:34.291 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2018-11-28 07:30:34.292 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'testdata1'; URL [testdata1]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.297 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'testdata1'; URL [testdata1]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.297 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Rendering view with name 'testdata1' with model {} and static attributes {}
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [testdata1] in InternalResourceView 'testdata1'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1fd05c8
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/main/testdata1]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@1c0cccc] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/main/testdata1]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@154b7ce] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /main/testdata1
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/main/testdata1]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@cb639d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : No handler mapping found for [/main/testdata1]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@121a2f5] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/main/testdata1] are [/**]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/main/testdata1] are {}
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/main/testdata1] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@cfb656]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-11-28 07:30:34.298 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@ec05ba]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@b2e8e5]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/main/testdata1] is: -1
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Resolving resource for request path "main/testdata1"
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [resources/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [resources/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [static/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [static/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [public/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [public/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: ServletContext resource [/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: ServletContext resource [/]
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : No matching resource found - returning 404
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 TRACE 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1fd05c8
2018-11-28 07:30:34.299 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8085-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Currently the main class is configured like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(
                SampleWebAppWebConfigurer.class,MainApp.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

The webMVC Configure is something like this:

```
@ComponentScan({"sampleprograms.controller"})
public class SampleWebAppWebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:\\webapp\\resources\\static\\")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }
}
```

The controller am using to load the html file is

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/main"})
public class DataController {
    static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(DataController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = {"/allList"})
    public String getGroups(HttpSession session) {
        LOG.error("The servlet context " + session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/testdata1"));
        return "testdata1";

    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"", "/"})
    public String getTestPath(HttpSession session) {
        LOG.error("The servlet context " + session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/testdata"));
        return "testdata";
    }
}
```

The URL am invoking to call the html is

> http://localhost:8085/main
>   http://localhost:8085/main/allList

The application properties file is

```
server.port=8085
#server.servlet.context-path=/api
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
logging.level.org.springframework: [![TRACE][1]][1]
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
#logging.level.root=TRACE
```

Am thinking the POM might be also needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>sampleprograms</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-programs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>sampleprograms</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>sample-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sampleprograms</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>sample-webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Finally, the project structure is something like this

[image: structure]

Comment: Here's the official documentation for serving static content in spring boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content. It tells where you should put your resources, and specifically tells not to put them under webapp (which, BTW, is NOT in the classpath).

Comment: It also say that you should NOT use EnableWebMVC, as this removes all the MVC autoconfiguration of Spring BOOT

Comment: I tried putting it under the resources folder too. Not much luck. Thanks.

Comment: But it doesn't say you should put them under resources. It says (first sentence): "Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) **in the classpath**" (emphasis mine. So put your static resources under `src/main/resources/static`, so that they end up, once built, under /static in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks., am packaging this as a war file and according to spring documentation, the web app is ignored only when packaged as a Jar., in addition, am overriding the WebMvcConfigurer class to add the classpath., I did update some changes I made to the original post.

Comment: But your automated tests are not run against a war file, so you'd better use something that works in both cases.